# Why 'subscribe' doesn't trigger when chain pipe with 'select' from NgRx in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I have two examples of code, and I can't understand why second example is not working. For me they are equivalent.

First example is working:

```
this.someValue$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(someValue),
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$$)
);
this.someValue$.subscribe(someValue => this.someValue= someValue)
```

And second example is not working when the store has changes, it triggers only once:

```
this.store.pipe(
  select(someValue),
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$$)
).subscribe(someValue => this.someValue= someValue);
```

So in second example I try to not create the redundant variable 'someValue$' and subscribe to the the store with 'select' inside pipe immediately. But as I mention above it doesn't work when some changes happens in store. In first example it works fine.

Both examples run in OnInit Angular hook.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have other pieces of code interfering with this... the two layouts are exactly the same (in the perspective of setting "this.someValue") .  if you could build a minimum reproducible example in  https://stackblitz.com/ it would get you more specific help

Comment: @TheFabio yeah, agree. Need to build the example, will try to do that when will have time